# Finding changes associated with a version in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, version-control

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with multiple sheets/tabs. When I access the Version history, it highlights the changes associated with the selected version if they are in the current sheet. However, if the changes associated with the selected version are not in the current sheet, I have to click through all of the sheets (and scan through the sheets that are bigger than my monitor screen) trying to find the changes. Is there a way to quickly find the changes associated with a specific document version in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1):

I feel a little stupid, but I found the answer. In the upper righthand corner there is an

Edits # of # ^ v

interface which will take you directly to the changed cells.[image]